# How to add multiple conditional formatting in VBA coding - EXCEL

Tags: vba, excel

How do I code multiple conditional formatting ? Currently, I'm only able to code a single conditional formatting.

MY CODE:

```
Sub Button5_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Set ws = Sheets("COMPARISON")
i = 1

With Range("I2:I146").FormatConditions.Add( _
    Type:=xlExpression, _
    Formula1:="=((($I2-$E2)/$E2)*100) > 20")
    .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

End With

Do Until i = 300
   If ws.Range("I" & i).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
       msg = "I" & i & " -" & " Data has changed"
       MsgBox msg
   End If
i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

I have manage to create one conditional formatting, where if the value of I2 - E2 is more than 20%, fill the cell red.

I wish to create two more conditional formatting such where

1) if the cell is 0 fill the cell black and set the font white

2) if the cell I2 is < E2 but not 0 fill the cell yellow.

Could someone help me with the other 2 conditional formatting ? Many thanks.

Comment: Can't you just record the conditions?

Comment: my "boss" doesn't want the idea of recording the conditions....

Comment: Plus if i do record the conditional formatting there too much codes in the vba and I'm not sure which code will be necessary, as I'm that pro/good in excel vba. So writing the vba code from scratch, I kinda understand the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just duplicated the `With` block and applied the conditions you have. You can try this:

```
Sub Button5_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Set ws = Sheets("COMPARISON")
i = 1

With Range("I2:I146").FormatConditions.Add( _
    Type:=xlExpression, _
    Formula1:="=((($I2-$E2)/$E2)*100) > 20")
    .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

End With

With Range("I2:I146").FormatConditions.Add( _
    Type:=xlCellValue, _
    Operator:=xlEqual, _
    Formula1:="0")
    .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End With

With Range("I2:I146").FormatConditions.Add( _
    Type:=xlExpression, _
    Formula1:="=AND($I2<$E2, $I2<>0)")
    .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
End With

Do Until i = 300
   If ws.Range("I" & i).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
       msg = "I" & i & " -" & " Data has changed"
       MsgBox msg
   End If
i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: @Joel it would be nice to mark my answer as the correct one. :)